# Хорошая ли это практика создавать дополнительную разметку для мобильной версии?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, теория

Имеется такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью `bootstrap` разместил элементы таким образом, как показано на картинке.

На мобильной версии картинка идет уже внутри первого блока

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, нормально ли это, что я буду создавать в первом блоке дополнительную разметку под картинку и скрывать ее пока экран не достигнет определенного размера? Или что нужно делать в таких случаях?

Comment: Почему бы не сделать кнопку третьим блоком (с отрицательным margin-top для первого случая, к примеру), а первые два блока просто по вертикали выстроить?

Comment: Или наоборот, не две картинки, а две кнопки, и скрывать кнопку